# how to perform action when the floating label change the state in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, calendar, onclicklistener, android-textinputlayout

I have a Edittext inside the TextInputLayout. I want to do that when i click on this textinputlayout then calender is also open.but in my case the floating label change the state and when i click on the edittext then the calender is opening.but i don't want to do that i want that when the user clicks at the first time on the TextInputLayout the floating label change and the calender is also open with it.can anyone tell me how can i do this ??

This is my xml :-

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_dob"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlack">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/DateOfBirth"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/date"
                        android:inputType="none"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And this is my on click listner on the edittext :-

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.DateOfBirth:

                new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

                break;

         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the OnFocusChangeListener to react when the TextInputLayout is clicked for the first time (which means the EditText inside the TextInputLayout gains focus)

```java
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
  @Override public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    //Open the calendar
    new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
  }
});
```

The "lambda version" will be:

```java
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> 
   new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show());
```

Comment: You are right. but when i go to the previous fragment the focus of the edittext is again changed.then the calender pop up is showing again. how can i resolve this .